# Eval compare of two values to FALSE only when both are not null and don't Match

Tags: sql, oracle

Where clause:
I should test column against value in Proc, but if at least one of them is null it should be TRUE as a result. Only when BOTH NOT NULL (it's Integer values for an ID column in a table) should the result of the compare be FALSE.

Now I have this:
...

```
and nvl(nvl(b.account_id, account_id_), 0) = nvl(nvl(account_id_, b.account_id), 0)
```

`b.account__id` - is Column in table (Integer), `account_id_` - Param in Proc of the same type.

It works, but IMHO it looks Strange to understand what is the purpose of the evaluation. 
So I tried to make it more READABLE, but without really good results.

I tried COALESCE - but it needs checking for null if both are nulls.
LNNVL is a good one, but it gives FALSE if THEY BOTH Equal, but I need True for this case.

Any good Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
and nvl(nvl(b.account_id, account_id_), 0) = nvl(nvl(account_id_, b.account_id), 0)
```

...is the same as:

```
AND COALESCE(b.account_id, account_id_, 0) = COALESCE(account_id_, b.account_id, 0)
```

Both are overly complicated.  If your parameter is null, there's no filter criteria on b.account_id because the value will match itself, or the null values will fall through to become 0 and therefore are equal.

You have your choice of the following:

```
AND b.account_id = COALESCE(account_id_, b.account_id)
AND (account_id_ IS NULL OR b.account_id = account_id_)
```

Both are portable syntax, but I lean towards using the COALESCE for sake of avoiding `OR`s where possible because of maintenance and sargability concerns.

Comment: I like COALESCE variant with '0' - it's OK.
I dont like 2nd one because of 2 evals - it's complicated also.
Thanks for pointing to COALSCE with Zeros - I missed this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it right, this should do it:
`(b.account_id IS NULL OR account_id_ IS NULL OR b.account_id = account_id_)`

Comment: Just as simple as it could be! Hmm... I should think about it tomorrow morning )))